# Symfony 3 - Doctrine 2.5 composite primary key not import

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to make a ***mapping:import*** with composite keys.
The problem is the table with the composite key is not imported.

Here is the sql example:

```
CREATE DATABASE composite_key;
USE composite_key;

CREATE TABLE company (
    id_company INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_company)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id_user INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(200) null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE reference (
    id_company INT NOT NULL,
    id_user INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_company,id_user),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_company) REFERENCES company(id_company),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
); 

INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES ('test1');
INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES ('test2');
INSERT INTO users (`name`) VALUES ('test3');

INSERT INTO company (`name`) VALUES ('company1');
INSERT INTO company (`name`) VALUES ('company2');
INSERT INTO company (`name`) VALUES ('company3');

INSERT INTO reference (`id_company`,`id_user`) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO reference (`id_company`,`id_user`) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO reference (`id_company`,`id_user`) VALUES (3,3);
```

Result execute query

[image]

After this I have create a new Symfony project without problems. Then I proceded make the import with the next comands

Generating data

```
php bin/console generate:bundle --namespace=CompositeBundle --format=yml
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import CompositeBundle
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities CompositeBundle
```

Finally we have the result:

[image]

It only creates users and company entities.

Somone Know why of this?

If you need the entities and the yml I will post them. I'm not posting them now beacause the post is getting to long.

Comment: just thoughts: Rather than use a composite key, i tend to use the standard `id` as the primary key. I would have a unique index for your composite key and use that for lookup etc. as required. That way the ORM is happy and I can use queries using the composite key when I want. i.e. no conflict / frustration between me and ORM. I like that. Foreign key relationships are efficient as they use the id maintained by the database. I have a extra test on 'composite key' sometimes. I don't mind that.

Comment: I thinked that solution. But I do not think that is right form for write these table. I mean if I can make it better I am gonna try the complex form before the easy way.

Comment: The problem is that primary keys also have implicit constraints like uniqueness. You can't make `id_user` or `id_company` unique on their own, because both can appear several times; however, the combination of a particular pair `id_user` +`id_company` cannot. This is why I'm not a fan of using autoincremental keys for these cases. If you're not very careful, you may be inserting the same relationship twice.